# What are the differences between the corruption and the crimson

Tags: terraria

The 1.2 patch of terraria introduced an alternate biome to the corruption called the crimson. What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crimson appears to be a substitute to the Corruption. The first world I created after installing the 1.2 update contained a Crimson biome, which also happened to take over a neighboring desert. Various differences with Crimson include:

- [Crimstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimstone) replaces stone
- [Crimsand](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimsand) replaces sand
- [Crimtane Ore](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimtane_Ore) replaces Demonite Ore
- [Crimson Altars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Altar) replace Demon Altars
- [Demon Hearts](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Heart) replace Shadow Orbs
- A few unique item drops
- A few unique enemies (Blood Crawler, Face Monster)
- A unique boss (Brain of Cthulhu)

Otherwise, I'm pretty sure Crimson can essentially be considered an equivalent to Corruption (it appears to spread over time in the same fashion, for example).

Comment: You also can't have both spawn in the same world.  You can import corruption from another world into one that has Crimson, but each individual world will only spawn one or the other.  Also, I'm not sure how true this is, but Crimson won't actually spread over desert (or snow!), it just generates a certain amount of corrupt material for those biomes at world generation.