# What items are mutually exclusive between worlds?

Tags: terraria

As of 1.2, some features are mutually exclusive between worlds.  In the case of ores at least, [these seems to serve as functionally identical replacements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132882/what-happened-to-all-the-copper).  However, a [Crimson biome](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson) gives you the chance for a [Panic Necklace](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Panic_Necklace) (and the upgraded Sweetheart Necklace) which does not seem to have an equivalent version in the Corruption.

What items, if any, are truly mutually exclusive in function between worlds?

Answer (score 5):

**Even though naturally spawning ores can be mutually exclusive between worlds, an [Extractinator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Extractinator) can be used to obtain the other ores.  Therefore, these ores themselves are not mutually exclusive.  This only applies to pre-hardmode ores**

**Hardmode Ores**

- Palladium vs Cobalt
- Orichalcum vs Mythril
- Titanium vs Adamantite

Palladium, Orichalcum, and Titanium items are slightly better than their Cobalt, Mythril, and Adamantite counterparts.

**[Crimson vs Corruption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132925/what-are-the-differences-between-the-corruption-and-the-crimson)**

- [Crimtane items](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimtane_Bar) as opposed to [Demonite items](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demonite_Bar)
- [The Undertaker](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Undertaker) as opposed to the [Musket](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Musket)
- [The Crimson Rod](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Rod) as opposed to [Vilethorn](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vilethorn)
- [The Rotted Fork](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Rotted_Fork) as opposed to [The Ball o' Hurt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ball_O%27_Hurt)
- [The Panic Necklace](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Panic_Necklace) as opposed to [The Band of Starpower](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Band_of_Starpower)
- [Vampire Knives](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vampire_Knives) as opposed to the [Scourge of the Corruptor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Scourge_of_the_Corruptor)

The monsters in the Crimson will drop Vertebrae as opposed to the Rotten Chunks found in the Corruption.  These will allow you to create the Bloody Spine which summons the Brain of Cthulhu as opposed to Worm food which summons the Eater of Worlds.  Either Vertebrae and Rotten Chunks can be used to create the Mechanical Worm.

Comment: Since my world only has one or the other of each element, I am using the wiki to fill in information for the parallel element.  Please correct any wrong information you find.

Comment: I have found a shadow orb (item) from a shadow orb drop in the corruption which seems to be exclusive. It summons a permanent, darker, version of the orb of light with no mana cost.