# Ores being odd?

Tags: terraria

Usually as said in most posts, about how tin/lead/tungsten etc. replace copper/iron/silver etc.
My worlds continue to have a mix of both (Like Copper, Lead, Tungsten, Gold) and I have no guarantee on what world may have the original hardmode ores. Is there anyway for me to know? Is there any reason the original and new ores keep mixing?

Comment: Also, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132985/what-items-are-mutually-exclusive-between-worlds

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Zibbobz's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/135344/56946) already stated: `Old and new ores mix between worlds`.

- Copper can become Tin,
- Iron can become Lead,
- Silver can become Tungsten
- and Gold can become Platinum.

As for Hardmode ores:

- Cobalt can become Palladium,
- Mythrill can become Orichalcum
- and Adamantite can become Titanium.

These combinements are always a mix, meaning you will never get the full set of either the old ones, or the new ones. However, every craftable weapon of the new ore has slightly better stats than the old ones. But also provide limitations for crafting, tools for example.

Answer (score 0):

Old and new ores mix between worlds.  The ores that mix are randomly selected for each world.  The only way to find out which ones you got is by finding them in the game.

The Extractor can give you any random ore, including ones that your world did not generate.